# Memory leak training ANN using multiple files

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, neural-network, fann

My loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= epochs; ++i) {
    for (std::vector<std::filesystem::path>::iterator it = batchFiles.begin(); it != batchFiles.end(); ++it) {
        struct fann_train_data *data = fann_read_train_from_file(it->string().c_str());
        fann_shuffle_train_data(data);
        float error = fann_train_epoch(ann, data);
    }
}
```

`ann` is the network, `batchFiles` an `std::vector<std::filesystem::path>`. This iterates training data files in a folder to train the ANN as many times as determined by `epochs`. This causes a memory leak:

```
struct fann_train_data *data = fann_read_train_from_file(it->string().c_str());
```

I must switch between files as I don't have enough memory. Why does a memory leak happen and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I am not familiar with ANN, but the [documentation here](http://leenissen.dk/fann/fann_1_2_0/r670.html) suggests that `fann_destroy_train` should be called on each iteration.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, memory is automatically freed when the object managing it goes out of scope.  (Assuming the class was properly written.)  That's called [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii).

But FANN presents a C API, not a C++ API.  In C, you need to manually free memory when you're done with it.  By extension, when a C library creates an object for you, it typically needs you to tell it when you're done with the object.  The library doesn't have a good way to figure out on its own when the object's resources should be freed.

The convention is that whenever a C API gives you a function like `struct foo* create_foo()`, you should be looking for a corresponding function like `void free_foo(struct foo* f)`.  It's symmetrical.

In your case, as originally noted by PaulMcKenzie, you need `void fann_destroy_train_data(struct fann_train_data * train_data)`.  From [the documentation](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_destroy_train), emphasis mine:

> Destructs the training data and properly deallocates all of the associated data.  **Be sure to call this function after finished using the training data.**

Answer (score 2):

Since the `fann_destroy_train_data` is required to be called, you can utilize C++ and RAII using the following wrapper:

```
struct fann_wrapper
{
   fann_train_data *td;
   fann_wrapper(fann_train_data* p) : td(p) {}
   ~fann_wrapper() { fann_destroy_train_data(td); }
};
//...
for (int i = 1; i <= epochs; ++i) {
    for (std::vector<std::filesystem::path>::iterator it = batchFiles.begin(); it != batchFiles.end(); ++it) {
        struct fann_train_data *data = fann_read_train_from_file(it->string().c_str());

        // the next line ensures that fann_destroy_train_data is called
        fann_wrapper fw(data);

        fann_shuffle_train_data(data);
        float error = fann_train_epoch(ann, data);
    }  // when this curly brace is encountered, the fann_destroy_train_data is always called
}
```

The `fann_wrapper` simply holds the `fain_train_data` pointer, and on destruction of `fann_wrapper`, the `fann_train_data` is destroyed.

The reason why this is much safer than the raw `C` method is in the case where a possible exception could be thrown (for whatever reason).  If an exception is thrown, then the `fann_train_data` will *always* be destroyed when using the `fann_wrapper`.  That guarantee cannot be made with the `C` method, since an exception would totally skip over any line that had the `fann_destroy_train_data`.

Example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= epochs; ++i) {
    for (std::vector<std::filesystem::path>::iterator it = batchFiles.begin(); it != batchFiles.end(); ++it) {
        struct fann_train_data *data = fann_read_train_from_file(it->string().c_str());
        fann_shuffle_train_data(data);
        float error = fann_train_epoch(ann, data);

        fann_destroy_train_data(data); // this line is not executed if an exception is thrown above, thus a memory leak
    }
}
```

This is why RAII is an important concept in C++.  Resources will get cleaned up automatically, regardless of the reason why the executable block of code is exited (exception thrown, a `return` is done, etc.).